# Shooting objects in a circular pattern SpriteKit

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, sprite, skaction

I don't really know how to explain what i'm after, so I drew some (very) artistic diagrams to help convey the idea. I'll also try and explain it the best I can.

I'm essentially trying to 'shoot' bullets/lasers/whatever from a circle in the center of the screen, and for it to repeat this at a rather rapid rate. Here are two pictures which kind of show what i'm trying to achieve: (Don't have enough reputation to post them here.

(1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/aemMG.png
This is kind of where I want the bullets to shoot from, and how many I'd like.

(2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmk9b.png
This is pretty much the end result, I'd like them to repeatedly fire and make the screen kind of look like this.

Can anyone refer me to what I should be looking at in order to achieve this?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with in your implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with circles, it's usually easier to use polar coordinates. In this case, each direction can be represented with a magnitude and an angle, where the magnitude is the amount of the force/impulse to apply to the bullet and angle is the direction to shoot the bullet.

The basic steps are

1. Determine the number of directions
2. Determine the angle increment by dividing 2*PI (360 degrees) by the number of directions
3. Start at angle = 0
4. Shoot bullet in the direction specified by angle
5. Convert the angle and magnitude to cartesian coordinates to form a vector
6. Apply an impulse or a force to the bullet using the vector
7. Increment angle by angle increment

Here's an example of how to do that in Obj-C:

```
@implementation GameScene {
    CGFloat angle;
    SKTexture *texture;
    CGFloat magnitude;
    CGFloat angleIncr;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    long numAngles = 15;
    magnitude = 1;

    angleIncr = 2 * M_PI / numAngles;
    angle = 0;

    texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

    SKAction *shootBullet = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        SKSpriteNode *bullet = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
        bullet.size = CGSizeMake(8, 8);
        bullet.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:bullet.size.width/2];
        bullet.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
        bullet.position = self.view.center;
        bullet.zRotation = angle-M_PI_2;
        [self addChild:bullet];
        CGFloat dx = magnitude * cos(angle);
        CGFloat dy = magnitude * sin(angle);
        CGVector vector = CGVectorMake(dx,dy);
        [bullet.physicsBody applyImpulse:vector];
        angle = fmod(angle+angleIncr,2*M_PI);
    }];

    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.25];

    SKAction *shootBullets = [SKAction sequence:@[shootBullet, wait]];

    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:shootBullets]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want this sprite to shoot a bunch of projectiles every X seconds.

```
    SKAction *ShootProjectiles = [SKAction runBlock:^{ 
                        //Create Projectile1
                          projectile1.physicsBody.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(1, 0)); //Shoot directly right
                          //Create Projectile2
                          projectile2.physicsBody.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(1, 1)); //Shoot diagnally Up and to the right
                          //Follow this pattern to create all projectiles desired to be shot in one burst

    }];

   SKAction *delayBetweenShots = [SKAction scaleBy:0 duration:5];
   SKAction* ShootSequence= [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[ShootProjectiles, delayBetweenShots]]];
   [self runAction: ShootSequnce];
```

What this does is create as many projectiles as you desire and fire them in the direction of the vectors you define.  It then waits 5 seconds (the scaleBy:0 action does nothing except delay) and then repeats over and over again until you remove the action.